# Can we use split function on the fields used to join in a hive query

Tags: sql, join, split, hive, hiveql

For example, I have two hive tables A and B.

> select split(a.field,':')[1] from A a join B b on (split(a.field,':')[1] = b.field);

Here, A's field can be a string of form "xyz:abc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.
This returns one row as expected:

```
select split(a.field,':')[1] 
  from ( select 'a:a' as field )  a 
        join ( select 'a' field ) b on split(a.field,':')[1]=b.field;
```